# Storm - KeeperException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm running a storm cluster. I have a nimbus, zookeeper, Kafka server, and a supervisor in one node,
and another supervisor in a separate node.

When I deploy the topology which has a simple Kafka-spout in the first node. The supervisor in second node throws run time exception.

But it works fine with the supervisor in the first node. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask some questions regarding your topology:
1. How are you ensuring that spout executor runs only on first supervisor node? It can run on any supervisor node.
2. Supervisor node registered correctly in the cluster? I mean this node shows on UI? Because as per the exception, it seems zookeeper does not aware of this node.
3. If spout runs on first supervisor node means that kafka config parameters like hostname might have been specified like "localhost". So when spout runs on first node, it contacts the localhost only for kafka queue. And if spout tries to run on second supervisor node, it fails because, for him "localhost" is itself and there kafka queu is not there.

--Hariprasad

Comment: 1. I checked it in the Storm UI. 2. Yeah, It shows up in the UI. 3. It is properly configured. But still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with Storm versions before 0.6.2. We tried running Zookeeper on a separate node and the issue was resolved, but we soon upgraded our version of Storm and no longer faced the issue. Try to run Zookeeper on a separate node and see if that helps. Also check if you have correctly configured the supervisors in the cluster. Check this [Google Groups Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/_L6i2JLjQwA) to see if you have correct configuration options.

Comment: Yeah, I will consider trying this. But I'm using `Storm version 0.9.1`.